# Implement Video Calling without any third party SDK in IOS

Tags: java, android, ios, asp.net, server

I am developing video calling functionality with web without use any third party. So Please suggest any idea for starting this video calling process and requirements.(like iOS side requirements, server side etc) because I am trying to search on google but I got only third party SDKs integration.

Answer (score 1):

Best route would be using Googles WebRTC. Otherwise you'd have to handle the encoder/decoder, handshake, and a TON of other stuff which is an absolute NIGHTMARE.

So the steps would be
integrate WebRTC into your iOS app (Google has a demo app you can use. It's code pasta but very very useful)

integrate mediator server for exchanging SDP (offer/answers) usually a socket connection

And paying for a TURN server (not expensive) in case the clients cannot connect directly.

It's super cool and fun, but very complex and brain boiling.

Few tidbits

Video streaming is very complex. This is a heavy task. Check out this
https://medium.com/leaningtech/porting-a-c-multiplayer-game-to-the-web-with-cheerp-webrtc-and-firebase-29fbbc62c5ca
for a real basic primer on how WebRTC works.
You're going to hit a lot of edge cases (frozen frames, poor connectivity, etc), just be ready.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to learn how to implement the UDP protocol because in a case like that i think UDP is your saver